Sorting a list based on custom comparator while not changing the place of negative numbers
Sorting a list of integers except negative numbers in java , negative numbers indexes should remain same
I tried to achieve above condition using a custom comparator but it fails
list.sort((a,b)->(a<0||b<0)?0:a-b);

Input list -
40,20,-2,0,-5,25,-3,44,24,29,38
Output list -
0,20,25,40,-2,-5,-3,24,29,38,44
Output expected -
0,20,-2,24,-5,25,-3,29,38,40,44
What's wrong with above comparator based approach? Can this problem be resolved using comparator?

There's no reason that saying all negative numbers are equal will cause them to stay in the same location during a sort. They'll often be compared with non-negative numbers.

@Gene if either one of the values is negative ,no matter if the other one is positive or not , comparator is considering them equal by returning 0

Good instinct in trying to solve your problem using existing libraries instead of re-inventing the wheel^^.
In your case, regrettably, you need to allocate a new List of the elements you actually want to sort before you can use List.sort.
Where you can read up:
While you formally defined a "Comparator", you did not fulfil the contract a java Comparator is always expected to fulfil. What you must implement is the compare function, which has to "ensure that compare(x, y)==0 implies that signum(compare(x, z))==signum(compare(y, z)) for all z.". Yours does not do this:
signum(compare(1, -1) = 0, but signum(compare(1,2))!=signum(compare(-1,2).
What you need to understand:
What you give the List.sort() as an argument, is not an instruction on how to react when it decides if to reorder two elements or not, you give it a description of the desired output, which has to be a total ordering.
When you tell List.sort (a,b)->1, this means "in the desired output I want to see all occurences of b before all occurences of a".
You can't describe your desired output in such a way, it just is no total ordering of Integers, so can't be expressed by a Comparator.

edited, thanks.


Can this problem be resolved using comparator?

No. What you need to do is monitor the location of the negative numbers and completely ignore them in the sort which is not possible with a comparator.  I would recommend something like the following.
List<Integer> original = new ArrayList<>(
        List.of(40, 20, -2, 0, -5, 25, -3, 44, 24, 29, 38));


sort the original list assigning to an interim list, filtering out the negative values.
Now allocate the result list to hold the final sort.
iterate over the original list, and merge the two lists together,
grabbing the negative value from the original list and the positive ones from the interim list.

List<Integer> interim = original.stream().filter(i->i >= 0).sorted().toList();
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
int k = 0; // interim index.
for (int i = 0; i < original.size(); i++) {
    int value = original.get(i);
    if (value < 0) {
        result.add(value);
    } else {
        result.add(interim.get(k++));
    }
}
System.out.println(result); 

prints
[0, 20, -2, 24, -5, 25, -3, 29, 38, 40, 44]

Note that I did not use List.add(index, value) to insert the negative values in the interim list.  Doing so would result in sliding all elements to the right in the interim list for each negative value encountered.  For large lists this would be very inefficient.  As it was done, you incur only O(n) additional overhead above the sorting overhead.

Consider a list like [-1, 3, -1, 2, -1, 1, -1]. Your approach would require a Comparator that knows that 1 precedes 2 and 2 precedes 3 (so that it will sort the nonnegative elements in order), but also believes that all of those values are equivalent to −1 (so that it will happily put (say) a 2 between two copies of −1). There is simply no way to do that.
There are a few approaches you could take instead, but the simplest is to extract the nonnegative elements into a separate list, sort that list (using a normal Comparator), and then go through the original list replacing its nonnegative elements with the elements of the sorted list.
